# Racket BSL: How can I combine two instances of a structure in a list that have one common attribute?

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages, htdp

I have a list of instances of a structure called "contact", which is basically a phone number and the duration a call with them took.

I now want to add together all entries of the same phone number with the total duration of all calls with them.

E.g: i want to turn:

```
(list
   (make-contact "0111222222" 2)
   (make-contact "0111222222" 6)
   (make-contact "0111333333" 5)
   (make-contact "0111444444" 3)
   (make-contact "0111555555" 8)
   (make-contact "0111555555" 2))
```

into:

```
(list
   (make-contact "0111222222" 8)
   (make-contact "0111333333" 5)
   (make-contact "0111444444" 3)
   (make-contact "0111555555" 10))
```

Im using Racket BSL with List abbreviations

Answer (score 0):

This works with htdp/bsl (i'm curious if there is a cleaner solution):

```
#lang htdp/bsl

(define-struct contact (number time))

(define contacts (list
   (make-contact "0111222222" 2)
   (make-contact "0111222222" 6)
   (make-contact "0111333333" 5)
   (make-contact "0111444444" 3)
   (make-contact "0111555555" 8)
   (make-contact "0111555555" 2)))

(define (sum-contacts acc s)
    (cond [(empty? s) acc]
          [(and (not (empty? acc))
                (equal? (contact-number (first s))
                        (contact-number (first acc))))
            (sum-contacts (cons
                            (make-contact
                               (contact-number (first s))
                               (+ (contact-time (first s))
                                  (contact-time (first acc)))) (rest acc))
                (rest s))]
          [else (sum-contacts (cons (first s) acc) (rest s))]))

(reverse (sum-contacts '() contacts))
```

Comment: I don't think `foldl` exists in BSL either, it's only introduced in ISL

Comment: ok, will check it letter today, btw i found out that lang should be "htdp/bsl" and yes it doesn't support fold and hashes :(

Comment: I updated the solution, it works with htdp/bsl language setting.